# Input Parameter in Web API

Tags: asp.net, json, http, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I need to implement web API. All methods in my controller are POST methods. Some methods just accept only one parameter. For that I get the input parameter from client as JSON.

For ex,

```
{
    studentId : 3
}
```

I need model validation in API. How can achieve this. Do I need to create a model for each request with single parameter?

Comment: Do you want to throw same type of validation for all single parameter Post request? if so you can take a look at Parameter Binders and put in something there. Other options can be Action Filters.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking at Data Annotations in your Model:

```
public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 99)]
        public double Age { get; set; }
    }
```

You could then use ModelState.IsValid to check if the input is valid or not:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(Student student)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
```